# Rails, EC2, Nginx, Unicorn - New assets are no longer rendering in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2

New assets that I add are no longer showing up on my production site (on EC2). It previously worked and the older images, stylesheets, and .js files are working, however anything new that I add is not rendering.

When I run

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV="production"
```

I get the following message with no errors:

```
yarn install v1.9.4
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files    generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by  unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.09s.
```

But then in my nginx error log there are a series of errors like the following for all my assets that have recently been added:

```
2018/10/19 16:59:13 [error] 5875#5875: *9800 open() "/home/deploy/production/
{appname}/public/assets/images/social.svg" failed (2: No such file or directory), 
client: xx.x.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "GET /assets/images/social.svg HTTP/1.1", 
host: "{appname}.com", referrer: "http://{appname}.com/"
```

I was not the one who originally set this up and I'm not clear as to what is causing the problem and would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. I've been reading everything I can find to figure this out, but I'm getting nowhere.

**production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.serve_static_files = false        
  config.assets.compile = true              
  config.assets.digest = true            

  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/assets/fonts"
  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/assets/images"
  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/assets/javascripts"
  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/assets/stylesheets"
  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/assets/pdf"

  #config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb', '*.css.scss' '*.svg' '.png' '.jpg']
  #config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf .png )
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  config.force_ssl = false
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "byc1_#{Rails.env}"
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.log_level = :info
  RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new('log/production.log')  
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

end
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/bcrypto**

```
upstream bcrypto_unicorn {
    server unix:/home/deploy/production/{appname}/tmp/sockets/bcrypto_unicorn.todo.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default deferred;
    root /home/deploy/production/{appname}/public;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header ETag "";
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @bcrypto_unicorn;

    location @bcrypto_unicorn {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://bcrypto_unicorn;
    }

    error_page 422 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
}
```

**config/initializers/assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( alphabetical_paginate.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
```

Comment: After you run `assets:precompile` do you see the precompiled assets showing up under `public/assets`?

Comment: They show up but they are all either red or pink, while the old ones are green.

Comment: The difference in color is likely difference in permissions. That might be a clue.

Comment: I set all permissions with chmod 755 so they're all the same and the different colors remained